# Powershell: Read mapped drives from user's NTUSER.DAT file

Tags: powershell-3.0

My goal is to use Powershell to load & analyze a user's old NTUSER.DAT file for any mapped drives they had on a previous profile, so we can automate mapping drives in a profile migration script.

So far I'm able to load in the user's registry hive. To test, I'm just trying to pull the mapped drives from the current user's HKCU, instead of the loaded hive under HKLM. Using the following code:

```
$path = Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Network\Z -Name RemotePath | Select RemotePath
```

This returns: 
`@{RemotePath=\\server\share\folder}`

I need to only get the \\server\share\folder part, so I can dump that into a variable, and use later on in the script to remap. I thought about trying some complicated string parsing, but thought there must be an easier way to just return the path, and not the "@{RemotePath=" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine ExpandProperty would do the trick;

```
$path = Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Network\Z -Name RemotePath | Select -ExpandProperty RemotePath
```